# how to convert metres to miles in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here its the distance giving is in metres i guess. The output is distance 7084232.923955827. How to convert the distance to miles?

```
 var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
        AppString.defaultLat,
        AppString.defaultLat,
        widget.restaurant.latitude ?? 9.9261153,
        widget.restaurant.longitude ?? 78.1140983);
        print('>>>>>>>>>> Distance $distance');
        return distance;
```

Comment: Why should this be specific to flutter? Just do normal math. eg. https://www.unitconverters.net/length/meters-to-miles.htm

Comment: thanks for the response.. MATH calculation will do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find distance between two point in km:

```
  double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371;
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}
double deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.pi/180);
}
```

convert km to meter

```
distance = distance * 1000;
```

**convert meter to mile** (distance is meter)

```
var mileFromMeter = distance / 1609.344;
```